# How to do browser launch using robotframework-selenium2library in an UNIX vm?

Tags: virtual-machine, robotframework

I want to launch a browser with head less or not in a remote Linux VM, but the I'm doing this using SSH connection to a remote Linux VM. What is the best way to launch google.com in a remote Linux VM using robotframework-selenium2library ?

Comment: I was able fix this issue using below pacakges
xvfbwrapper
robotframework-xvfb
robotframework-selenium2library

*** Settings ***
Documentation     This example demonstrates how to use current library
Library      Selenium2Library
Library      XvfbRobot
*** Test Cases ***
Create Headless Browser
    Start Virtual Display    1920    1080
    Open Browser   http://google.com
    Set Window Size    1920    1080
    ${title}=    Get Title
    Should Be Equal    Google    {title}
    [Teardown]    Close Browser

Comment: Please reenter your comment as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able fix this issue using below pacakges xvfbwrapper robotframework-xvfb robotframework-selenium2library

```
*** Settings *** 
Documentation   This example demonstrates how to use current library 
Library  Selenium2Library 
Library  XvfbRobot 

*** Test Cases *** 
Create Headless Browser Start Virtual Display 1920 1080 
  Open Browser google.com 
  Set Window Size 1920 1080 
  ${title}= Get Title Should Be Equal Google {title} 
  [Teardown] Close Browser
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to have anything to do with a remote VM. It opens the browser on whatever machine/vm the robot test is running on.